# How to convert AWT font to SWT font? SWT incompleteness: impossible to use font name from file

Tags: java, fonts, awt, swt, type-conversion

I am working with fonts as data. And these fonts are in AWT format. I would like to have a font sample in a TableView in my eclipse application. Unfortunately, SWT has it's own Font class. How does it relates with AWT? And is it possible to convert one font to another?

My AWT fonts are obtained from TTF files with the code

```
in = getClass().getResourceAsStream(fileNames[i]);
font = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, in).deriveFont(FontSize);
```

It is important that fonts be exactly of that files.

**UPDATE**

Incredible! Looks like `SWT` authors imagined themselves cool enough to create their own and separated `Font` implementation, so that the only correspondence left is by file. But their hands trembled and they forgot to implement font name determination!

**UPDATE 2**

I have prepared TTF file, which is actually `Times New Roman` font, but in which all names were changed to Arial. I named this file `arial_actuallytimes.ttf`.

The I ran the following program

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws FontFormatException, IOException
    {
        Display display = new Display();
        Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));

        // The font file
        File fontFile = new File("arial_actuallytimes.ttf");
        // Get the font name from AWT
        Font awtFont = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, fontFile).deriveFont(12f);
        String fontName = awtFont.getFontName();
        shell.setText(fontName);

        // Load the font in SWT
        display.loadFont(fontFile.getAbsolutePath());

        // Get the font instance with the name we got from AWT
        final org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Font swtFont = new org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Font(display, fontName, 12, SWT.NORMAL);

        // Use the font
        Label label = new Label(shell, SWT.BORDER);
        label.setFont(swtFont);
        label.setText("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog");
        label.addListener(SWT.Dispose, new Listener()
        {
            @Override
            public void handleEvent(Event arg0)
            {
                swtFont.dispose();
            }
        });

        Composite frameHolder = new Composite(shell, SWT.EMBEDDED);
        frameHolder.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.CENTER, true, false));
        //frameHolder.setLayout(new FillLayout());

        JLabel jLabel = new JLabel("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog");
        jLabel.setFont(awtFont);

        JPanel jPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        jPanel.add(jLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        Frame frame = SWT_AWT.new_Frame(frameHolder);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.add(jPanel);
        frame.pack();

        shell.pack();
        shell.open();

        while (!shell.isDisposed())
        {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch())
                display.sleep();
        }
        display.dispose();
    }
```

the result was following

[image]

which means that SWT had not recognize the font as Times New Roman. Probably it was distracted by `Arial` which is in the system by default and it took default `Arial`.

**UPDATE 3**

File sample: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1jZw9H7L4gmTjUwYURhU0lkeGM/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
Device.loadFont(file path);
```

to load a font - this requires a file path rather than a resource stream.

You would then use

```
new Font(device, "font name", height, style);
```

to create the SWT font.

Comment: Note to the OP: Remember to `dispose()` `Font`s you create this way.

Comment: But where is the connection between first and second lines? If device can contain only one font loaded, then what for the "font name" parameter is? Or if this parameter plays some role, then how to guarantee that namely that font will be used?

Comment: Device can load many fonts. The font is made available using the font name that is part of the loaded font data. You have to specify that font name in the Font constructor.

Comment: How to know the name of the font I just loaded?

Answer (score 1):

Based on @greg-449's answer, I came up with this. All that was missing was a way to get the font name:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FontFormatException, IOException
{
    Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    // The font file
    File fontFile = new File("DIN.ttf");
    // Get the font name from AWT
    String fontName = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, fontFile).deriveFont(12).getFontName();

    // Load the font in SWT
    display.loadFont(fontFile.getAbsolutePath());

    // Get the font instance with the name we got from AWT
    final org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Font swtFont = new org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Font(display, fontName, 12, SWT.NORMAL);

    // Use the font
    Text text = new Text(shell, SWT.BORDER);
    text.setFont(swtFont);
    text.addListener(SWT.Dispose, new Listener()
    {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event arg0)
        {
            swtFont.dispose();
        }
    });

    shell.pack();
    shell.open();

    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
            display.sleep();
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

Comment: How one can be sure, that font name, returned by `AWT` is the same that and applicable to `SWT`? Especially if they are completely separated? Why `SWT` creators forgot to create their own implementation to track font names? Suppose I had no any `AWT` code at all. How could I use font from file this case, only by `SWT` means?

Comment: @SuzanCioc I don't know why it's done this why in SWT, but why exactly do you not want to Use AWT in this care? It's part of every java runtime and seems to work just fine.

Comment: See my update, looks like it doesn't. May be I made a mistake, but looks like `SWT` identifies font incorrectly by `AWT` name.

Comment: No, everything was Ok except small error with `deriveFont()` parameter, which should be `12f` not `12`. So, I have updated my post. And it looks like absolute proof that `AWT` name is not matching.

Comment: Also passed font name to the title. It is "Arial" which is correct name. But actual glyphs are from `Times New Roman`, so `SWT` behaves incorrectly.

Comment: @SuzanCioc Could you please explain your case? I'm struggling to understand why you would want to use fonts that interfere with system fonts. Are you not in control of the fonts being used?

Comment: I am working with fonts as data. I need to make them absolutely portable, so I am to use system font names, but should use specific files for them.

Comment: @SuzanCioc Can you upload the file you have been testing with?

Comment: @SuzanCioc Alright, I tried around a bit and it seems impossible to make SWT use your custom font **if** you're using the same name as a system font. My workaround would be to append a prefix to all your portable fonts, so that the identifier (the name) differs from the system fonts.

Comment: I see. Fortunately, I can utilize `AWT` in major part. Also I can use `AWT` embedder. Not sure how it will behave in numerous instances inside `TableViewer` :)